# Turning a python dict. to an excel sheet

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having an issue with the below code.

```
import urllib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ny.com/clubs/nightclubs/index.html').read())
clubs = []
trains = ["A","C","E","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","N","Q","R","L","B","D","F"]
for club in soup.find_all("dt"):
    clubD = {}
    clubD["name"] = club.b.get_text()
    clubD["address"] = club.i.get_text()
    text = club.dd.get_text()
    nIndex = text.find("(")
    if(text[nIndex+1]=="2"):
        clubD["number"] = text[nIndex:nIndex+15]
    sIndex = text.find("Subway")
    sIndexEnd = text.find(".",sIndex)
    if(text[sIndexEnd-1] == "W" or text[sIndexEnd -1] == "E"):
        sIndexEnd2 = text.find(".",sIndexEnd+1)
        clubD["Subway"] = text[sIndex:sIndexEnd2]
    else:
        clubD["Subway"] = text[sIndex:sIndexEnd]
    try:
        cool = clubD["number"]
    except (ValueError,KeyError):
        clubD["number"] = "N/A"
    clubs.append(clubD)
keys = [u"name", u"address",u"number",u"Subway"]
f = open('club.csv', 'wb')
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
dict_writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in clubs])
```

I get the error ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames. I dont understand how this could be. Any assistance would be great. I am trying to turn the dictionary into an excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clubs` is a list of dictionaries, whereas each dictionary has four fields: name, address, number, and Subway. You will need to encode each of the fields:

```
# Instead of:
#dict_writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in clubs])

# Do this:
for c in clubs:
    # Encode each field: name, address, ...
    for k in c.keys():
        c[k] = c[k].encode('utf-8').strip()

    # Write to file
    dict_writer.writerow(c)
```

#### Update

I looked at your data and some of the fields have ending new line `\n`, so I updated the code to encode and strip white spaces at the same time.